# Debundle - webpack

Tags: webpack

[image: bundle]

I am trying to debundle this already built JS files. I'm not sure about the debundle config json. What should I do to produce a successful output?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"entryPoint": 0` in `debundle config json` fixed my problem.